# HTML - Build a responsive web page

Tags: html, css

I want to divide the homepage into three ***responsive*** main sections horizontally: a **header**, a **body** and a **footer**, and then divide the body part into three ***responsive and equal*** vertical sections.

Please suggest a way to do so

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Divide sections horizontally

There are many ways to do that, and by default most `HTML` tags are stacked horizontally of top each other, but to fix a **header** on top of everything and and a **footer** below everything, without leaving the page even when scrolling you need to use the `position: fixed` rule with the `top, left, bottom and right` values adjusted to your design's needs. In the example below we stick the `div` with class `header` to the top of the screen, by setting the `top: 0`, and make it span the full width by specifying the `left: 0;` and `right: 0;` properties, the same goes for the `.footer` but it is sticking to the bottom instead using `bottom: 0;`. Then we have the `div` with class `body` to contain the rest of your page, we need to give it a `margin-top` equal to the `.header`'s height in order to prevent hiding content below the `.header`, the same goes for `margin-bottom` and the `.footer`'s height.

### Divide the body vertically (responsively)

This is achieved easily by giving the `width` of elements using percentages, so if you need to divide the `.body` div into three columns, each should span the third (33.33%), and that is achieved by setting the `width: 33.333%`. Now to show inner `div`s on the same line you need to set the `display` property to `inline` (or other inline values) and make sure the `margin` is zero because it is not counted in the `width` property.

Of course there are **many alternatives** to do that, but this is an example on how to do it:

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 70px;
  background: #4286f4;
  text-align: center;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 70px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.body {
  background: green;
  margin: 70px 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.body_v1, .body_v2, .body_v3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 33.333%;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.body_v1 {
  background: #42f465;
}
.body_v2 {
  background: #108928;
}
.body_v3 {
  background: #034210;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="body">
  <div class="body_v1">a</div>
  <div class="body_v2">b</div>
  <div class="body_v3">c</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

After all, my advice is that you use a third party framework to achieve this instead of reinventing the wheel, there are [many examples](https://www.google.jo/search?q=css%20frameworks&oq=css%20frameworks&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i65j69i60j69i59j69i60.4127j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) out there you can have a look and choose the one that more suits you.

Comment: @skag The answer was updated to include some explanation

Comment: Thank you for the explanation